# Can't select data attr when added with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am adding some data to data attr with jquery when click button

```
$(document).on('click','.musicButton',function(){
 var genre = $('.musicPlay').last().data('genre'); 
 var musicBox = $($('#musicBoxTemplate').html());
 $(musicBox).appendTo('.allMusics');
 $('.getData').last().data('music',genre);
}
```

Then I need when that data

```
$(document).on('click','.musicPlay',function(){
 var data = $(this).data('genre');
 var music = $('.getData[data-music=' + data + ']');
 if( music.find(':first-child').attr('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'em'{
 //Do some stuff
 }
}
```

that alert me undefined. why it don't see that data when I need?

Comment: Change your .data to .attr

Comment: I changed that alert($(getData).attr('data')); still return me undefined

Comment: You need to change all the .data to .attr not just the alert.

Comment: It's still not working I'm trying to when I click red button it define a data to red box. then when I click red box I am trying get data with ajax for that box.

Comment: Can you share the code with the AJAX call?

Comment: my problem is with that var getData = $('.getData[data-data=' + data + ']'); this is not working.

Comment: @Abuzettin and what do you want to do by this line ?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim I edited my question. var music = $('.getData[data-music=' + data + ']'); that data selector is not working.

Comment: Post you html code lets see how you setted your data attribute

Comment: @MichaelDawn There is no html code with data attribute. I added my html with that line var musicBox = $($('#musicBoxTemplate').html()); defined data attr with that line $('.getData').last().data('music',genre);

Comment: when I alert or consolog that $('.getData').last().data('music') it works fine.

Comment: Your code is not consistent. If you're able to successfully alert the value of your $('.getData').last().data('music') , ask yourself what is different between how you're trying to access this in your condition that you are having trouble with. Modify the condition selector to match the working alert and compare the alerted value to the expected value.